# Shiny app bundle doesn't deploy in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

My shiny app bundle does not deploy in shinyapps.io. My app runs perfectly in rstudio, but doesn't run in shinyapps.io. After deployment, I get the following log message in my rstudio console:

```
> rsconnect::deployApp(appDir="mavisanalytics")
Preparing to deploy application...
Update application currently deployed at
https://mavisanalytic.shinyapps.io/mavisanalytic/? [Y/n] y
DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 2244614...DONE
Deploying bundle: 3143405 for application: 2244614 ...
Waiting for task: 730944890
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 3509314
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 3509314
  deploying: Starting instances
  rollforward: Activating new instances
  terminating: Stopping old instances
Application successfully deployed to https://mavisanalytic.shinyapps.io/mavisanalytic/
>
```

But the shiny app never runs on shinyapps.io after deployment. Below is my list of dependencies:

```
 rsconnect::appDependencies(appDir="mavisanalytics")
              package  version source
1                  BH 1.72.0-3   CRAN
2                MASS 7.3-51.6   CRAN
3              Matrix   1.2-18   CRAN
4                 NLP    0.2-0   CRAN
5                  R6    2.4.1   CRAN
6        RColorBrewer    1.1-2   CRAN
7                Rcpp  1.0.4.6   CRAN
8   SentimentAnalysis    1.3-3   CRAN
9             askpass      1.1   CRAN
10         assertthat    0.2.1   CRAN
11          backports    1.1.6   CRAN
12              callr    3.4.3   CRAN
13                cli    2.0.2   CRAN
14          codetools   0.2-16   CRAN
15         colorspace    1.4-1   CRAN
16             crayon    1.3.4   CRAN
17               curl      4.3   CRAN
18         data.table   1.12.8   CRAN
19               desc    1.2.0   CRAN
20             digest   0.6.25   CRAN
21              dplyr    0.8.5   CRAN
22                dtt    0.1-2   CRAN
23           ellipsis    0.3.0   CRAN
24            english    1.2-5   CRAN
25           evaluate     0.14   CRAN
26              fansi    0.4.1   CRAN
27             farver    2.0.3   CRAN
28            fastmap    1.0.1   CRAN
29            foreach    1.5.0   CRAN
30            ggplot2    3.3.0   CRAN
31             glmnet    3.0-2   CRAN
32               glue    1.4.0   CRAN
33             gtable    0.3.0   CRAN
34          htmltools    0.4.0   CRAN
35        htmlwidgets    1.5.1   CRAN
36             httpuv    1.5.2   CRAN
37            isoband    0.2.1   CRAN
38          iterators   1.0.12   CRAN
39           jsonlite    1.6.1   CRAN
40           labeling      0.3   CRAN
41               lars      1.2   CRAN
42              later    1.0.0   CRAN
43            lattice  0.20-38   CRAN
44            lexicon    1.2.1   CRAN
45          lifecycle    0.2.0   CRAN
46           magrittr      1.5   CRAN
47               mgcv   1.8-28   CRAN
48              mgsub    1.7.1   CRAN
49               mime      0.9   CRAN
50            moments     0.14   CRAN
51            munsell    0.5.0   CRAN
52            ngramrr    0.2.0   CRAN
53               nlme  3.1-139   CRAN
54            openssl    1.4.1   CRAN
55            packrat    0.5.0   CRAN
56             pillar    1.4.4   CRAN
57           pkgbuild    1.0.8   CRAN
58          pkgconfig    2.0.3   CRAN
59            pkgload    1.0.2   CRAN
60              plogr    0.2.0   CRAN
61             praise    1.0.0   CRAN
62        prettyunits    1.1.1   CRAN
63           processx    3.4.2   CRAN
64           promises    1.1.0   CRAN
65                 ps    1.3.2   CRAN
66              purrr    0.3.4   CRAN
67   qdapDictionaries    1.0.7   CRAN
68          qdapRegex    0.7.2   CRAN
69       randomForest   4.6-14   CRAN
70             reactR    0.4.2   CRAN
71          reactable  0.1.0.1   CRAN
72              rlang    0.4.6   CRAN
73          rprojroot    1.3-2   CRAN
74          rsconnect   0.8.16   CRAN
75         rstudioapi     0.11   CRAN
76             scales    1.1.0   CRAN
77              shape    1.4.4   CRAN
78              shiny  1.4.0.2   CRAN
79       shinyWidgets    0.5.1   CRAN
80         shinyalert      1.1   CRAN
81    shinycssloaders      0.3   CRAN
82            shinyjs      1.1   CRAN
83        shinythemes    1.1.2   CRAN
84               slam   0.1-47   CRAN
85        sourcetools    0.1.7   CRAN
86          spikeslab    1.1.5   CRAN
87         stringdist  0.9.5.5   CRAN
88            stringi    1.4.6   CRAN
89                sys      3.3   CRAN
90            syuzhet    1.0.4   CRAN
91                tau   0.0-21   CRAN
92           testthat    2.3.2   CRAN
93          textclean    0.9.3   CRAN
94          textshape    1.7.1   CRAN
95             tibble    3.0.1   CRAN
96              tidyr    1.0.2   CRAN
97         tidyselect    1.0.0   CRAN
98                 tm    0.7-7   CRAN
99               utf8    1.1.4   CRAN
100             vctrs    0.2.4   CRAN
101       viridisLite    0.3.0   CRAN
102             withr    2.2.0   CRAN
103              xml2    1.3.2   CRAN
104            xtable    1.8-4   CRAN
105              yaml    2.2.1   CRAN
106               zoo    1.8-8   CRAN
>
```

Could I still be missing a key dependency from a package?

Comment: confused at your question... if you go here: https://mavisanalytic.shinyapps.io/mavisanalytic/ as shown in your deployment log, a dashboard loads...

Comment: Hi Kevin, the dashboard you see in that url is very different from the shiny app that I built and run locally. If you don't mind, can I share my shiny app code with you, so you can run it locally?